After Upgrading Ubuntu to 24.04 LTS clang does not work properly
I am trying to compile some code with clang++, but I receive an error that for examle iostream could not be found. I know that clang uses the gcc headers by default, so when I compile with g++ everything is fine.
Any idea? I have already reinstalled it everything, but the problem persists.
Update: It now works only with clang++ -lc++ Hello-world.cpp -o Hello-world
Update:
❯ clang++ -v -Wall -std=c++23 main.cpp -o main
Ubuntu clang version 18.1.8 (9ubuntu1~24.04)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/lib/llvm-18/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -dumpdir main- -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -debugger-tuning=gdb -fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/dejo -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/dejo -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-18/lib/clang/18 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++ -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-18/lib/clang/18/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -Wall -std=c++23 -fdeprecated-macro -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-implicit-modules -fskip-odr-check-in-gmf -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -dwarf-debug-flags "/usr/lib/llvm-18/bin/clang --driver-mode=g++ -v -Wall -std=c++23 main.cpp -o main -dumpdir main-" -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /tmp/main-6edf0e.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 18.1.8 based upon LLVM 18.1.8 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++
 /usr/lib/llvm-18/lib/clang/18/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
    1 | #include <iostream>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.


This question is similar to: How do I install clang 18 on Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@graham That duplicate link doesn't work according to Code4Fun. I copy/pasted his comment to that effect into the main question. As you can verify by reading my answer, that sort of thing works fine on my Ubuntu 24.04, but it doesn't work the same way on the asker's Ubuntu 24.04.


Uninstall all old versions of clang and install the latest version.
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get remove clang-* 
cd /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/
sudo rm -r 8
sudo apt install clang clang-18 clang-tools-18 g++-13 libstdc++-dev

Results of clang++ --version should be:
Ubuntu clang version 18.1.3 (1ubuntu1)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin


Save the following C++ code in Hello-world.cpp.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello, world" << endl;
    return 0;
}


Compile it with clang++ Hello-world.cpp -o Hello-world

Run the compiled code with ./Hello-world



The problem still persists. It works only with clang++ -lc++ Hello-world.cpp -o Hello-world

@Code4Fun I think I managed to solve it. Please check my first code block.

No, sorry. I think maybe there is a symbolic link issue? Btw I had already the recent libstdc++-dev installed.

How thoroughly horrible. Verify that the necessary C++ libraries are available in the expected paths. Running clang++ -v Hello-world.cpp -o Hello-world can provide detailed output about what libraries and paths clang++ is using during the compilation.

I put the output

In my Ubuntu 24.04 the default gcc version that I have installed is provided by the gcc-13 package, and according to your output your gcc version is gcc-14.

Ok, why it is so? when I run gcc --version, it tells me 13.3.0 ...

One time I installed gcc-14 and libstdc++-14-dev and it worked, or I purged everything about gcc-14 and it worked, too... but in both cases I have linker problems in projects where I used sdl2 for example or Catch2 ...

I have the same problem running on x64.  The proposed workaround, above, is for aarch64 and doesn't work here for misc reasons.
However I did learn that if I install g++-14 in particular, that makes my hello world clang++ actually build and run.  It seems to be that the clang package does not capture its dependencies correctly.
I agree that this is thoroughly horrible.  I would think Canonical would not release a major version of their system with a common, important, well-used package broken like this.  I would be wrong.
The system is not usable for me as it is and I am going away until it works.  Or I'll stay on Mint.  Just posting this if others want to get their clang to, uh, actually work in the meantime.

I had same thing happen to me, as I need to compile with clang/++ for Emacs lsp-mode.
   Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14
   Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14

Good.
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/.../..."

WT$%#$%#!!!

Verify actually exist.  In my case did not.  Like the warning ("ignoring") stated.
sudo apt install libstdc++-14-dev to fix.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libstdc%2B%2B-14-dev&searchon=names&suite=noble&section=all
Clang uses gcc headers https://clangd.llvm.org/guides/system-headers
So whether 24.04 is shipping with placeholders for gcc14 or non-dev version of gcc14, idk.
Caveat: Just found out today, Nvidia driver doesn't play nice with setting system to clang/++, so I assume it is not recommended practice in general.
To check:
update-alternatives --get-selections | grep c

To set
sudo update-alternatives --config cc
sudo update-alternatives --config c++

If you build system uses system environment variables for c/c++ (e.g. CMake)
Someone recommended export over -DCMAKE... compiler flags.  Seems legit.
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++

P.S.  I do not remember if I had to do any symlinks.  ln -s ... ... 
